# Using OpenLayers ZoomBox in JavaFX WebView

Tags: javascript, webview, javafx-8, openlayers, javafx-webengine

I am using JavaFX `WebView` included in jdk-8u45 to open a web page which shows a map using OpenLayers 2.13.1. I'm trying to zoom in on the map using a `ZoomBox` with a `BoxHandler`. The zooming works like it should, but the problem is how the the rectangle is drawn.

The wanted result is that once I click on the map and start dragging, the rectangle should start drawing as I move the mouse. This works fine in all browsers, except inside my `WebView`. What happens is that only after I have moved my mouse a few cm in both x- and y-direction (e.g. diagonally), the rectangle starts drawing from this position (not the one where I started dragging). I have looked at the coordinates from the different mouse events, and they all seem to be correct, which is confirmed by the fact that it zooms in on the area I actually dragged over (e.g. not the area that is drawn).

JavaScript `console.log` stmts output coordinates from the moment I click on the map, but nothing is drawn in the beginning of the drag.

Has anyone had similar problems with `WebView`? As I said, the code works like a charm in all other browsers I have tried (Safari, Firefox, Chrome, IE). I have looked around on the internet, but I haven't been able to find an answer to my problem.

Code taken from `BoxHandler.js`:

```
startBox: function (xy) {
    ;;;console.log(xy);
    ;;;console.log("startbox xy=" + xy.x + "," + xy.y);
    if(this.zoomBox){
        this.removeBox();
    }

    this.zoomBox = OpenLayers.Util.createDiv('zoomBox',
                                             this.dragHandler.start);
    this.zoomBox.className = this.boxDivClassName;
    this.zoomBox.style.zIndex = this.map.Z_INDEX_BASE["Popup"] - 1;
    this.map.viewPortDiv.appendChild(this.zoomBox);

    OpenLayers.Element.addClass(
        this.map.viewPortDiv, "olDrawBox"
    );
},

/**
* Method: moveBox
*/
moveBox: function (xy) {

    var startX = this.dragHandler.start.x;
    var startY = this.dragHandler.start.y;

    ;;;console.log("dragHandler.start.x=" + this.dragHandler.start.x);
    ;;;console.log("dragHandler.start.y=" + this.dragHandler.start.y);

    var deltaX = Math.abs(startX - xy.x);
    var deltaY = Math.abs(startY - xy.y);
    this.zoomBox.style.width = Math.max(1, deltaX) + "px";
    this.zoomBox.style.height = Math.max(1, deltaY) + "px";
    this.zoomBox.style.left = xy.x < startX ? xy.x+"px" : startX+"px";
    this.zoomBox.style.top = xy.y < startY ? xy.y+"px" : startY+"px";

    console.log("zoombox width=" + this.zoomBox.style.width);
    console.log("zoombox height=" + this.zoomBox.style.height);
    console.log("zoombox left=" + this.zoomBox.style.left);
    console.log("zoombox top=" + this.zoomBox.style.top);

    // depending on the box model, modify width and height to take borders
    // of the box into account
    var box = this.getBoxCharacteristics();
    ;;;console.log("movebox xOffset=" + box.xOffset);
    ;;;console.log("movebox yOffset=" + box.yOffset);
    if (box.newBoxModel) {
        if (xy.x > startX) {
            this.zoomBox.style.width =
                Math.max(1, deltaX - box.xOffset) + "px";
        }
        if (xy.y > startY) {
            this.zoomBox.style.height =
                Math.max(1, deltaY - box.yOffset) + "px";
        }
    }
},

/**
* Method: endBox
*/
endBox: function(end) {
    var result;
    console.log(this.map.viewPortDiv.lastElementChild.style);
    if (Math.abs(this.dragHandler.start.x - end.x) > 5 ||
        Math.abs(this.dragHandler.start.y - end.y) > 5) {
        var start = this.dragHandler.start;
        var top = Math.min(start.y, end.y);
        var bottom = Math.max(start.y, end.y);
        var left = Math.min(start.x, end.x);
        var right = Math.max(start.x, end.x);
        result = new OpenLayers.Bounds(left, bottom, right, top);
    } else {
        result = this.dragHandler.start.clone(); // i.e. OL.Pixel
    }
    this.removeBox();

    this.callback("done", [result]);
}
```

Also, I don't know if this is relevant, but when I inspect the HTML `div` element that holds the map (using Firebug Lite) it looks like the top border of the `div` is further down than it should be. The map (in correct position on the webpage) is extending beyond the top border. This is different behavior than in the other browsers I mentioned.

Any help would be appreciated.